# Ubuntu freeze and more installation problems

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, live-usb, amd-graphics

I have an hp pavillion notebook, Amd A9-9410 radeon R5 cpu, amd radeon r7 M440 graphics card.
I 'v burned the iso into a usb stick using rufus. After I boot and click try ubuntu or install it starts normally and after a minute everything freezes and have to shut down. I added the acpi=off parameter and i was able to install ubuntu but after I couldn't even get to the login screen. It either gave me a black screen with hundreds of "amd-vi completion-wait loop timed out" errors or tells me to fsck the sda7 partition which I do manually and then again nothing. I even tried opening with the acpi=off and other tricks I've found over the forums but nothing worked.

Comment: To get useful help, please edit your question to describe in detail all those tricks you have tried. Otherwise, those will be the first solutions we recommend.

Comment: By tricks i mean changing the bios settings with legacy boot and security boot plus trying nomodeset and iommu=soft commands.